# Архитектура DB для мессенджера

Tags: android, mysql, sql, база-данных, messenger

Как грамотнее с точки зрения оптимизации сделать БД для мессенджера?

Варианты:

1. Сделать три таблицы:

   messages:

   id         - идентификатор сообщения 
   to_id      - внешний ключ для связи с таблицей users (сообщение адресовано)
   from_id    - внешний ключ для связи с таблицей users (сообщение отправлено)
   content_id - внешний ключ для связи с таблицей msgContents (содержимое сообщения)
   created_at - время создания сообщения
   updated_at - время редактирования сообщения

   msgContents:

   id         - идентификатор сообщения
   content    - содержимое сообщения

   Ну и users само собой...
2. Или же для каждого чата делать отдельную таблицу.

Comment: 1 вариант, связываешь таблицы чтоб все было атомарно.

Comment: А зачем отдельная таблица для msgContents если там только id сообщения и содержимое? Почему не засунуть содержимое в messages?

Comment: Для того, чтобы понять как правильно организовать данные (стоит ли декомпозировать дальше или наоборот нарушить нормализацию в угоду скорости), стоит сначала определиться, какие запросы чаще всего будут к базе, а именно: Будет только вставки/удаление или редактирование? По каким полям чаще всего будет отсев при выборке?

Comment: Ну и конечно нужна отдельная таблица для чатов. Иначе чтобы получить все чаты для юзера придётся перебирать все сообщения. Одна таблица, а не как в вашем втором варианте.

Comment: Для этого существует проектирование проектов и создание workflow архитектуры клиента, ядра, баз данных и тд. Все же зависит от цели. У вас это какой-то кусочек и тот очень плох, ну посмотрите сами. Где состояние сообщения?  Где тип сообщения? Какая связность у бд, что есть у других моделей. Напишите структуру классов в Java, поднимите FireBase, попередовайте сообщения и все станет ясно.

Comment: Если хотите примеров, рекомендую поставить SQLite и посмотреть базы данных у того же skype. Вот вам реальная локальная база данных мессенджера. Заодно и разберётесь какими сущностями надо оперировать, а то сейчас у вас картина не полная.